# How do I fully specialize a function template with a class template?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, explicit-specialization

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
   ... // do stuff with type T
}

template <typename T>
class class_template
{
    // class body
};

template<>                       // failed attempt at full specialization
void foo(class_template<T> t)    // which doesn't work of course
{
    //full specialization for all classes of class_template
}
```

In the above code how do I explicitly specialize function foo with a class template?

Comment: The contradiction here is that if it's "for all classes of class_template", then it's not a "full specialization". A full specialization by definition applies to only *one* possible value of each template parameter.

Comment: Your attempt has `template<>` but then uses an undeclared template parameter `T`, which can't work, what is `T`? As the previous comment says, you're using the wrong terminology, what you're trying to do is **partially** specialize a function template, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above code how do I explicitly specialize function foo with a class template?

You cannot. This is the whole point of partial specialisations. But they don’t work for functions.

You have two solutions:

- Overload the function. This usually works.
- Refer the work to a class template, which *can* be partially specialised. That is, inside your function, call a (static) function in a class template, and specialise *that*.

Comment: I don't think I have either choice, as my function foo is std::swap.

Comment: @hawk:  Because you're still requiring a template parameter.  For example, `template<> void foo< class_template<int> > (class_template<int> t)` is legal because it no longer has a template argument.  Where you want to say, "for all class_templates, do this", which is not.

Comment: @hawk Just overload `std::swap` in the local namespace. This is the preferred way.

Comment: @hawk:  One other thing, rather than specialize std::swap, use function overloading, which is how the STL containers work.  In the same namespace as your class_template, put `template <typename T> swap(class_template<T> &lhs, class_template<T>& rhs) {...}`.

Comment: @hawk: you should ADL-overload `swap` (that is, define a function `swap` in the same namespace as `class_template`). If you're paranoid also check that your standard library does `swap(a,b);` rather than `std::swap(a,b);` in algorithms like `sort`. Users of swap should use it like `using std::swap; swap(a,b);`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Yea that's what I was worried about. How do I check that?

Comment: @hawk: either look at the source, or sort some of your objects and log how many times their copy constructors are called.

Comment: @hawk: Or you could put a printout in your swap function to see if it's being invoked when you sort.